# The usage of let in Haskell

Tags: haskell, variable-assignment

I have this code in Haskell.

```
import Data.List

main = do
    putStrLn $ "\nVerify if Exists in a String"
    let wordlist = ["monad", "monoid", "Galois", "ghc", "SPJ"]
    let tweet = "This is an example tweet talking about SPJ interviewing with Galois"
    print $ map (flip isInfixOf tweet) wordlist
```

Without the `let`, I have this error message: `10_things.hs:16:14: parse error on input ‘=’`.

This is another code that works fine.

```
import Data.List

wordlist = ["monad", "monoid", "Galois", "ghc", "SPJ"]
tweet = "This is an example tweet talking about SPJ interviewing with Galois"      
main = do
    putStrLn $ "\nVerify if Exists in a String"
    print $ map (flip isInfixOf tweet) wordlist
```

In this case, I have error `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)` with let. 
My question is when and when not to use `let` in Haskell?

Comment: `do` notation is not as easy as it looks like: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation + http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html#io.bind

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declarations/equations need to be inside either a `let` or a `where` block. The reason you don't need `let` at the top level of a module, is that it counts as a `where` block all by itself, started by its `module` declaration.  A module which doesn't contain an explicit `module` header gets an implicit

```
module Main (main) where
```

at the beginning.

By the way, an indented `let` block can contain more than one declaration: you don't need the second `let` in your code as long as the equations line up vertically.

Answer (score 10):

Haskell has two ways to introduce names: `let` and `where`.

You use `let` whenever you could have a normal expression. This can come up in two places: if you're defining a normal value and if you're inside do-notation. In the first case, you would use `let ... in` to introduce a name just within a single expression:

```
myFoo = let x = 10 ^ 10 in x + x
```

Inside do-notation, you do not need an `in`; instead, the `let` takes up a line just like a normal "statement" in do-notation. This is what your first example has:

```
main = do
  let x = something
  ...
```

The other way to introduce names is with `where` clauses, which go *outside* of expression. The top-level of your program—where you define all the globally visible names in your module—is in a `where` block, which is why you just write `name = expression` without a `let`. This happens because your module implicitly has

```
module Main where
```

on top even if you didn't write it yourself.

You can also write `where` blocks of your own in different scopes, which also let you define names without `let`:

```
foo x = ...
  where helperA = something
        helperB = something
```

Comment: The top level `where` is so special I hate to even compare it to regular `where` clauses. There's also a `where` in a class declaration and a `where` in a GADT or closed type family declaration.

Answer (score -1):

```
do notation is for monads. I am guessing you are unclear about monads.
```

let used inside do notation is basically binding. the do notation translates to this form

```
do {let x = expression; restofit} ==> let x = expression in do {restofit}
```

For instance this

```
do 
 line1 <- getLine            -- executes an action
 line2 <- getLine            -- executes an action
 let joined = line1 ++ line2 -- pure calculation; no action is executed
 return joined
```

This translates to

```
let joined = line1 ++ line2 in line1 <-getLine >> line2 <- getLine
```